# How do I change values of hex in file and save again

Tags: hex

How do I change the last 6 values of hex in file and save again using vb or c or c++ or java

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Dim hexString As String
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles open_button.Click
    If open_openfiledialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Using file As New IO.FileStream(open_openfiledialog.FileName, IO.FileMode.Open)
            Dim value As Integer = file.ReadByte()

            Do Until value = -1
                hexString = hexString & (value.ToString("X2"))

                value = file.ReadByte()
            Loop
        End Using
        hex_richtextbox.Text = hexString
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles open_openfiledialog.FileOk

End Sub


Private Sub save_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_button.Click
    IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:myfile.ax2", hex_richtextbox.Text.Split(" "c).Select(Function(s) Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray())



End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I have also fixed your code formatting, each line must be preceded by 4 spaces.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "change the last 6 values of hex in file". Are there more bytes in your file and you want to change only the last 6 bytes? That is the question you are asking? How to move the read/write pointer of file to the end - 6 bytes?